# ur10 end-effector tf

Tags: ros, ur-modern-driver, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using ur10 ros driver to get the position of a mounted drilling pin on the end-effector of the robot. I want to do a transformation between the end-effector (`tool0_controller`) and  the drilling pin frames. I measured the distance and orientation between them and tried to do a static transformation as the following but can't see any changes when I echo the `/tf` topic

```
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="tool0_controller" args=" 
   0.5 0 2  
   0.707  0.707 0 0 
    /base_link/base /base_link/base/tool0_controller 500"/>
```

Any clue?

---

Edit: Simply the question is that I am trying to control a drilling pin that is mounted on the end-effctor of the ur10 robot (tool0_controller frame). I tried the static transformation above but it wasn't working

I tried to add a new frame to tool0_controller and this is the code I am using but the problem here is that:
the pose published by drillingPin frame is relative to the tool0_controller not to the base.

```
  #include <ros/ros.h>
  #include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>
  #include <geometry_msgs/PoseStamped.h>

  int main(int argc, char** argv){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "my_tf_broadcaster");
  ros::NodeHandle node;
  tf::TransformBroadcaster br;
  tf::Transform transform;

  ros::Rate rate(10.0);
  while (node.ok()){
    transform.setOrigin( tf::Vector3(0.0, 2.0, 0.0) );
    transform.setRotation( tf::Quaternion(0, 0, 0,1) );
    br.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(transform, ros::Time::now(), "tool0_controller", "drillingPin"));
    rate.sleep();
  }
  return 0;
  };
```

I am pretty sure this is a common application to universal robots but can't find useful tutorials.
Your help is highly appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316570/ur10-end-effector-tf/) by [raghad.husari](https://answers.ros.org/users/40097/raghad.husari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-02-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-25**:
Can you clarify what you want to do exactly? You cannot "override" a TF frame being published by `ur_modern_driver`, so that wouldn't work.

I'm also confused by this:

```
/base_link/base /base_link/base/tool0_controller
```

which frames are these supposed to be?

Finally: `500` is the period, not ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-25**:
.. the frequency/update rate, so this is only publishing at 2 Hz. Probably not what you intended.

**Comment by [raghad.husari](https://answers.ros.org/users/40097/raghad.husari/) on 2019-02-25**:
I mounted a drilling pin on the end-effector and want to get the position of that drilling pin from the ur driver. The position of the drilling pin is located at specific distance relative to the tool0-controller frame, let's say at x=0.5, y=0 and z=2 with no orientation.

**Comment by [raghad.husari](https://answers.ros.org/users/40097/raghad.husari/) on 2019-02-25**:
the parent frame is /base_link/base and the child frame is /base_link/base/tool0_controller, I am trying to apply a static transformation to shift the child frame to the drilling pin position

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-25**:
`tool0_controller` is a frame that is published by `ur_modern_driver`, you cannot "shift it". Your publisher will conflict with the driver.

I'm still confused, but I would recommend you introduce a *new* frame that encodes the location of your drilling pin relative to `tool0_controller`.

**Comment by [raghad.husari](https://answers.ros.org/users/40097/raghad.husari/) on 2019-02-27**:
Please see my reply below @gvdhoorn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This shouldn't be so difficult and wouldn't even require writing a custom TF broadcaster.

If you have a custom frame that is relative to `tool0_controller`, you have two options:

1. if it's a static frame (ie: does not include any dynamic rotation or translation): use `static_transform_publisher`. Something like this would add the frame you show in your edit:

   ```
   rosrun tf2_ros static_transform_publisher 0 2.0 0 0 0 0 1 tool0_controller drillingPin
   ```

   Two things to note:

   1. don't use uppercase characters in TF frame names (or any graph resource): see [wiki/Names](http://wiki.ros.org/Names).
   2. ROS uses metres for distances, so the `2.0` you have there results in a Y-translation of 2 metres relative to `tool0_controller`. Most likely not what you intended.
2. add `drillingPin` as a `link` to your composite xacro/urdf (the one that combines the UR xacro with your end-effector) and use a `fixed` type `joint` to link the two together. The `robot_state_publisher` will then do all the hard work for you.

Which of the two options you choose doesn't really matter I believe. The `static_transform_publisher` would need to run all the time, so would result in an additional node, but seeing as it's a static TF frame, won't result in too much overhead.

> I tried to add a new frame to tool0_controller and this is the code I am using but the problem here is that: the pose published by drillingPin frame is relative to the tool0_controller not to the base.

re: not relative to `base`: well, no. You specify it as a transform relative to `tool0_controller`, so it's exactly as you specified.

That doesn't mean you can't query TF for the transform between `base` and `drillingPin` though.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0